# jquery toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tyring to show/hide the content of a link when it's clicked. much like what you see in FAQ pages. Basically I want to get the data-* of the clicked link and display it's content. This is what I've done but it still doesn't work :(.

My html is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a data-faq="1" href="#question"> + first question product?</a></li>
        <p  data-faq="1" class="hidden">my content</p>

    <li><a data-faq="2" href="#question">+ More lorem?</a></li>
        <p data-faq="2" class="hidden">my content</p>

</ul>​
```

and jquery like this:-

```
 $('.hidden').hide();
 $("#question").click(function(){

 var activeFaq = $(this).attr("data-faq");    

    //show the content of the active faq
    $(activeFaq).toggle();
return false;
});

​
```

this is the fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/8EJDc/
again I'd like to toggle the `+` to `-` upon the toggle click and vice versa

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to toggle the visibility of an element?

Comment: please check the fiddle, but yep that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Santy: updated my answer with your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSBhc/1/)

Try this -

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a data-faq="1" class="question"> <span>+</span> first question product?</a>
        <p data-faq="1" class="hidden">my content</p>
    </li>       
    <li>
        <a class="question"><span>+</span> More lorem?</a>
        <p class="hidden">my content</p>
    </li>   
</ul>

$('.hidden').hide();
$(".question").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.text($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');  
    $(this).next('p').toggle();   
});
```

Comment: can the `+`possibly be toggled also?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of it please?

Comment: @Santy: I have fiddle in my answer below.

Comment: @Santy Please check updated fiddle - the selection is removed

Comment: @Dipaks yours is the most concise. However, I was wondering how I could possibly change the `+` and `-` to images. instead of text, Again how do I add that active effect when a particular question is clicked? here->  `www.facebook.com/help/cookies`. thanks very much bro :)

Comment: @Santy Check this fiddle with images - http://jsfiddle.net/nSBhc/3/ You need to modify that image a bit

Comment: @Dipaks, the fadIn fadeOut effect :( You've already done enough I know but I'd be glad. Check the page again in case you didn't see it `www.facebook.com/help/cookies` you see when a faq is clicked, there a quick fadeIn and fadeOut. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Man, you were so much on the wrong way.

You can't have a **P** inside a **UL** if it's not inside an **LI**.

You were trying to call an element by it's ID with $("#question"). But you didn't declare any ID.

I tried to rewrite your code:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a data-faq="1" href="#" class="question"> + first question product?</a>
    <p data-faq="1" class="answer">my content</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="question">+ More lorem?</a>
        <p class="answer">my content</p>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
$('.answer').hide();
$(".question").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".answer").toggle();
});
```

I changed some class names to put more semantic

Answer (score 1):

Change $('#question') is refer to element id.

And this could work:

```
$("a").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().next('.hidden').toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **HTML** Should look like as given below, because a `ul` only has `li` tags instead of any other tags. So keep your `<p>` tags inside an `<li>` tag.

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <a class="faq" href="#question"> <span class="symbol">+</span> first question product?</a>
        <p class="hidden">my content</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="faq" href="#question"><span class="symbol">+</span> More lorem?</a>
        <p class="hidden">my content</p>
    </li>            

</ul>​
```

And **jQuery** :

```
$('.hidden').hide();

$(".faq").click(function(event){    
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.hidden').toggle();

    // below Code will toggle 'plus' & `minus`
    if($(this).find('.symbol').html() == "+") {
         $(this).find('.symbol').html("-")
    } else {
         $(this).find('.symbol').html("+")    
    }

});
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s2x3M/)

Answer (score 0):

I found quite a few errors in your script. I fixed most of them and tried to achieve the thing you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/vvJPU/1/

Check this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell what the data-faq is for, or if you even need it.

But this seems to do what you want ... http://jsfiddle.net/vvJPU/3/

```
$('a.question').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: update not toggling. Please review it. and the + didn't also toggle

Comment: @Santy: I have updated it in my answer not in other's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is wrong. you should not call jquery of an anchor using its href attrib. It should be either class or id attrib. Also, instead of hidden, use $().css() .

```
<ul>
<li><a class="question" data-faq="1"  href="#question"> + first question product?</a></li>
    <p id="data-faq1" class="hidden">my content</p>

<li><a class="question" data-faq="2" href="#question">+ More lorem?</a></li>
    <p id="data-faq2" class="hidden">my content</p>
```

​

--

```
$('.question').click(function(){
var paraId = "#data-faq" + $(this).attr("data-faq");

$(paraId).click.toggle(function () {
        $(this).css("display","none");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("display","block");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i got what's your problem. but basically, i think it is closed.

here the code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $(".hidden").hide();
            $("ul li a").click(function(){
                $(this).next().text($(this).attr("data-faq")).toggle();
            });
    }
    );
</script>
```

Note: `<p>` should be inside the `<li>` and next to `<a>`

i think there's a problem with your HTML code. i noticed `<p>` it outside `<li>`

the content of data-faq will be the content of `<p>` tag

[Click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSBhc/4/)